# How to write to SD card with dd command?

Tags: dd, raspberry-pi, images, sd-card

Having some trouble with writing to my SD card, burning NOOBS (New Out Of Box Software) software to my SD card for Raspberry Pi. Attempted to use the following command as root:

```
# dd bs=1M if=/home/harrydevries/Downloads/NOOBS_v1_2_1 of=/dev/sdb
dd: reading `/home/harrydevries/Downloads/NOOBS_v1_2_1': Is een map
0+0 records in 
0+0 records out 
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0,00117138 s, 0,0 kB/s
```

Comment: What does "trouble" mean, exactly?

Comment: dd: reading `/home/harrydevries/Downloads/NOOBS_v1_2_1': Is een map
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0,00117138 s, 0,0 kB/s

Comment: Well it seems my map is empty anyway,strange!

Comment: With the added information left in comment and later updated in question, I'm really not sure what is unclear.

Comment: "Is een map" == "Is a directory" == A bit of an issue.  That won't work!  You can't `dd` a directory, and you don't want to use `dd` with NOOBS anyway...you need to copy a set of files onto a FAT32 formated card. But not with `dd`! `cp` is more appropriate...hopefully you have figured this out by now.

Comment: Yes some optimist made a example with dd command but indeed is cp the way to do this,but learning meanwhile,thanx for the tip anyway,

Comment: You don't need to use dd for NOOBS. Just use a normal copy command to copy the set of files and directories to the root of the SD card (formatted as one big FAT32 partition). Among the files are "bootcode.bin", the [second stage bootloader](http://elinux.org/RPi_Software#Overview). It doesn't need a boot sector and thus using a disk image file is not necessary. On the other hand, installing Rasbian usually entails using an .img file and thus dd may be required.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says *"Is een map"* which is Dutch for something like *"Is a directory"*.

You can't `dd` a directory. You have to have a file or another device as source and target. `if` and `of` respectively.

## Bad

```
dd if=/some/directory of=/another/file
dd if=/some/directory of=/some/device
dd if=/some/directory of=/some/directory
dd if=/some/device    of=/some/directory
dd if=/some/file      of=/some/directory
```

## Good

```
dd if=/some/file   of=/another/file
dd if=/some/file   of=/some/device
dd if=/some/device of=/some/file
dd if=/some/device of=/some/device
```

---

## When good goes bad

And as always when using `dd` – take care to get it correct.

```
dd if=/some/file of=WRONG_DEVICE
```

Comment: Thanx very much,this was indeed the mistake i made,

Comment: @HarrydeVries: Yes, understandable to make if one does not know `dd`. When it comes to the *real* operation, then yes, slm's links looks good. Anyhow. `dd` is a powerful tool. Only take care to do it right (don't overwrite your system disk etc.) when you use it ;).  This is perhaps far off. But when on the subject of NAND memory [this can be in the corner](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/How_to_Damage_a_FLASH_Storage_Device). Though using `dd` on a SD card is perfectly valid if it is same model, it is a backup, you take/write a backup, you backup/restore a partition, write MBR etc. It all depends.

Comment: … or if one do not care. I have flash memory I play with and likely destroy by misuse. But it is for educational purpose. I really want to get me a Raspberry Pi myself. Looks fun. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this page ([RPi Easy SD Card Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup)) for details on setting up NOOBS and Rasp Pi. This page has lots of details for various burning scenarios, too numerous to list here.

#### References

- [RPi Easy SD Card Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup)